# Record Type in column

Tags: visualforce, record-type

I want to display record type of each record in a pageblock table.

I have an object application with 3 record type
A pageblock table displaying all application. A column to display record type of each application in column1.

Is this possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Just add something like:

```
<apex:column value="{!theApplication.RecordType.Name}"/>
```

Depending on how you've built your page you may need to load this value is a SOQL statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it worked... loaded this value in SOQL stmt also...